# Create an IObservable from a method

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have such a method that performs a long query search against some data.

```
Task<List<SearchResult>> Search(string query){ ... }
```

I have tried various way to create an IObservable form of it but failed. At the end after some google help I wrote such a method.

```
private IObservable<SearchResult[]> Search(string query)
{
    return Observable.Create((IObserver<SearchResult[]> observer)=>
        {
            List<SearchResult> result = new List<SearchResult>();
            foreach (TestsGroupMeta group in Engine.Groups)
            {
                string name = group.ToString();
                if (name.IndexOf(query, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
                {
                    result.Add(new SearchResult{ Name = name, Type = "Group"});
                }

                foreach (TestMethodMeta method in group.Methods)
                {
                    name = method.ToString();
                    if (name.IndexOf(query, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
                    {
                        result.Add(new SearchResult {Name = name, Type = "Method"});
                    }
                }
            }

            observer.OnNext(result.ToArray());
            observer.OnCompleted();

            return () => {};
        });
}
```

Is such a method correctly written? If not, what would be correct?

Comment: Why do you want to use IObservable<T> rather than Task<T>?

Answer (score 4):

using the `TaskObservableExtensions` from `System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks` (in the [Rx Linq DLL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Linq/)) it is easy:

```
IObservable<List<SearchResult>> observable = Search(queryString).ToObservable()
```

I'd consider [the code there](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Threading/Tasks/TaskObservableExtensions.cs#L76) to be "correctly written" (I'm in no way linked to the code nor its authors.)

If you want to rewrite your `Search` method to work directly with `Observable`s I'd recommend using their full power:

```
private IObservable<SearchResult> Search(string query)
    {
        return Observable.Create<SearchResult>(
            (observer, cancellationToken) => Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () =>
                {
                    foreach (TestsGroupMeta group in Engine.Groups)
                    {
                        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        string name = group.ToString();
                        if (name.IndexOf(query, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
                        {
                            observer.OnNext(new SearchResult { Name = name, Type = "Group" });
                        }

                        foreach (TestMethodMeta method in group.Methods)
                        {
                            name = method.ToString();
                            if (name.IndexOf(query, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
                            {
                                observer.OnNext(new SearchResult { Name = name, Type = "Method" });
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    observer.OnCompleted();
                },
                cancellationToken,
                TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
                TaskScheduler.Default));
    }
```

An observer is now able to process `SearchResults` as soon as they are found (as opposed to wait for the completion of the computation yielding all results at once) and can unsubscribe anytime which in turn will cause a cancellation of the result computation. If some function still needs all `SearchResults`at once there's always `Observable.ToEnumerable` and friends. In addition, possible parallelization is now obvious (e.g. using [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx)) but still not trivial (hinted at by the inclusion of TaskCreationOptions and TaskScheduler, sensible options for Parallel.ForEach not included). Also clients must then be prepared to consume 'out-of-order' search results.

Potential further improvements:

- check for cancellation at more / more appropriate places
- split Task/Observable logic and searching
- handle (now asynchronous) errors (e.g. by `try`ing the `foreach` and calling `observer.OnError`)
- specify culture for`ToString`
- employ a more 'functional' style by leveraging `SelectMany` (suits my personal taste)

Otherwise you could at least use `Observable.Start` which gets rid of the otherwise unused observer:

```
private IObservable<SearchResult[]> Search(string query)
{
    return Observable.Start(() =>
    {
        List<SearchResult> result = new List<SearchResult>();
        foreach (TestsGroupMeta group in Engine.Groups)
        {
            string name = group.ToString();
            if (name.IndexOf(query, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
            {
                result.Add(new SearchResult { Name = name, Type = "Group" });
            }

            foreach (TestMethodMeta method in group.Methods)
            {
                name = method.ToString();
                if (name.IndexOf(query, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
                {
                    result.Add(new SearchResult { Name = name, Type = "Method" });
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    });
}
```